# how can I populate and retrieve table of record using java

Tags: java, sql, arrays, oracle, record

Package, in which I declared my Data Types

```
create or replace package pkg_var is
 type array_table is table of varchar2(50);
 type array_int is table of number;
 type p_arr_rec is record(p_no number,p_val varchar2(50));
 type array_record is table of p_arr_rec;
 end pkg_var;
 /
```

My procedure to populate record

```
create or replace procedure proc1(p_array in pkg_var.array_table,
arr_int in pkg_var.array_int,len out number,arr_rec out
pkg_var.array_record)
as
v_count number;
begin
len := p_array.count;
v_count :=0;
for i in 1..p_array.count
loop
--dbms_output.put_line(p_array(i));
arr_rec(i).p_no := arr_int(i);
arr_rec(i).p_val := p_array(i);
v_count := v_count+1;
end loop;
end;
/
```

This is my `class` to call the above procedure to populate array into table of record

```
public class TestDatabase {

    public static void passArray()
    {
        try{
            dbcon conn = new dbcon();
            Connection con = conn.dbstate().getConnection();

            String str_array[] = {"one", "two", "three","four"};
            int int_array[] = {1, 2, 4,8};
            ArrayDescriptor str_des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("SCOTT.PKG_VAR.ARRAY_TABLE", con);
            ARRAY arr_str = new ARRAY(str_des,con,str_array);
            ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("SCOTT.PKG_VAR.ARRAY_INT", con);
            ARRAY arr_int = new ARRAY(des,con,int_array);

            CallableStatement st = con.prepareCall("call SCOTT.proc1(?,?,?)");

            // Passing an array to the procedure -
            st.setArray(1, arr_str);
            st.setArray(2, arr_int);
            st.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
            st.registerOutParameter(4,OracleTypes.ARRAY,"SCOTT.PKG_VAR.ARRAY_RECORD");
            st.execute();

            System.out.println("size : "+st.getInt(3));

            // Retrieving array from the resultset of the procedure after execution -
            ARRAY arr = ((OracleCallableStatement)st).getARRAY(4);
             BigDecimal[] recievedArray = (BigDecimal[])(arr.getArray());

            for(int i=0;i<recievedArray.length;i++)
                System.out.println("element" + i + ":" + recievedArray[i] + "\n");

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        passArray();
    }
}
```

I'm getting `java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: SCOTT.PKG_VAR.ARRAY_TABLE` Exception, anyone help me to solve this exception.

One more question how do I retrieve table of record of `SQL` in `Java` ? My second question is for this code
`ARRAY arr = ((OracleCallableStatement)st).getARRAY(4);`

Is it a valid code to get `table of record` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want with PLSQL array types, you need to create 'Array Types' on the database, eg:

```
create or replace type rectype as object(col1 varchar2(10),col2 varchar2(10));
/ 
create or replace type rectypetab as table of rectype;
/
```

I describe how to use all this with Java here: http://betteratoracle.com/posts/32-passing-arrays-of-record-types-between-oracle-and-java

Comment: In the above link, I couldn't find to retrieve record of table

Comment: I don't have a full example of pulling back an array of records. I show how to retrieve a simple array http://betteratoracle.com/posts/26-passing-arrays-between-java-and-oracle-procedures and also how to retrieve a non-array record - http://betteratoracle.com/posts/31-passing-record-types-between-oracle-and-java If you put that together with the other link above you should be able to work it out. Basically you retrieve the array of records from Oracle, cast it back to a Java array (which is then an Array of Oracle structs) and then you cast each struct back to a Java array.